# How to send data from website to web server on raspberry pi?

Tags: php, c++, linux, raspberry-pi

Let's say that I have a website somewhere over the internet. At my house there is a raspberry pi.

Can I send data from that website to that raspberry pi?

I have web server on that raspberry pi, and I tried sending a POST request from website, and it worked, but now anyone, who knows how to send POST request can just send that data to raspberry pi. I want to send that data to C++ program, that I'll write. How can I do it?

Can I do it another way, or somehow secure that POST request?

Comment: You can simply ask for credentials on that posting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent your users from seeing that is being posted to the RasPi and from tampering with it, you'll need to send that data from the server, not from user's browsers.  You can still do this by POSTing to some sort of web service on the RasPi, or you can cache the information on the web server and poll it from the RasPi.  In either case, you should protect that flow by requiring that it take place over HTTPS (as opposed to plain-text HTTP) and authenticating the client using either a TLS client certificate or some sort of API key.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use SSL (secure transmission) - not perfect but will stop a lot
2. Use a 'nonce' (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30519/prevent-cross-domain-form-submission-with-nonce plus google).
3. Filter requests not coming from the correct IP address (assuming your web server will have a fixed outgoing IP address). [Side note: this is fakable so not perfect]
4. Individually encrypt each instructions manually, including a shared private key on your webserver and a unique ID embedded in each message. If you get exactly the same encrypted message it's a repeat post can be safely be dropped.